# Show multiple slides, move one using Bootstrap 3.3.5 carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried using this [code snippet](http://www.bootply.com/UUXYF5wGj3) to get Bootstrap's carousel to show 6 items, but only advance 1 and it works with Bootstrap 3.0.2, but when I try to use it with Bootstrap 3.3.5, it advances the full 6. The Bootply example with 3.3.5 is [here](http://www.bootply.com/yNdE51hs8o).

I'm not advanced enough in JS to know what I should be doing differently. Is this still possible?

Comment: I have tried this thing, it complicates a lot, when working with dynamic backend data in slides ! cloning and append -it creates a mess, my personal recommendation is to go for [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com) its responsive and fully customizable

Comment: I agree this method is very messy. Thank you for the suggestion, I am checking it out now!

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it may help someone. 
I didn't realize how messy this was either until I had to implement it.
This is the best solution I have seen so far because it's actually responsive. https://www.bootply.com/PMDIAzc1Qo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that the latest version of Bootstrap adds some extra classes for moving the slides. Adding this CSS to override Bootstrap's fixed the issue:

```
.carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(16.66666667%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(16.66666667%, 0, 0);
}

.carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-16.66666667%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-16.66666667%, 0, 0);
}
```

Fixed Bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/TaiPmPel17)