# Bootstrap and more then 1 item on carousel at once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've found really nice carousel modification for more then one item at once. Here is example Bootstrap 3.3 - http://www.bootply.com/123662. But **unfortunately after click on < > that don't seems to slide just one item like in 3.3 with Bootstrap 3.5**. Here is example - http://www.bootply.com/yNdE51hs8o.

What can be wrong? Someone can solve this?

html

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="carousel slide" id="cbutelki">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-lg-2"><img src="http://bagpak.thewebcookies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/c4ca4238a0b923820.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-2"><img src="http://bagpak.thewebcookies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/c81e728d9d4c2f636.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-2"><img src="http://bagpak.thewebcookies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/eccbc87e4b5ce2fe2.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-2"><img src="http://bagpak.thewebcookies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/a87ff679a2f3e71d9.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-2"><img src="http://bagpak.thewebcookies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/e4da3b7fbbce2345d.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-lg-2"><img src="http://bagpak.thewebcookies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/1679091c5a880faf6.png" /></div>
    </div>
   <div class="item">
     <div class="col-lg-2"><img src="http://bagpak.thewebcookies.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/8f14e45fceea167a5.png" /></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#cbutelki" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#cbutelki" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

.js

```
$('#cbutelki').carousel({
  interval: 4000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to post your code in your actual question, not just links to it. Links to sandbox editors are helpful, but they should be used to supplement the code, not as its only source. Please edit your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: That's much better! No the only other issue I can see is that you don't really explain what is wrong. *"But unfortunately that don't seems to work..."* doesn't give us much to work with, and both your bootply links work fine for me.

Comment: @TimLewis oh sorry. Too long in office today.

Comment: I feel ya. Better problem description there, but it does the same in both examples. If you click `>`, it slides to the next item. If you click `<` is spins 7 items to the left instead of 1 to the left. So technically 3.3 is just a broken as 3.5.

Comment: @TimLewis yep. But it some way > do the job. Maybe someone can figure it out for < >.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3.3.5 now uses `transform: translate3d`(where supported) for it's slide effect. Because of this the old method is broken. Below is a example of how it should be included in your example. Here's a working [Pen](http://codepen.io/Shawry/pen/vNbBYB) for you.

Here's a [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33593999/5006246) where I was struggling with a similar issue. The reason for the two separate media queries is explained in the post.

**Also I've corrected your Javascript to add an extra image in the following line in your for-loop (in case you were wondering why mine was showing 6 images while yours is only showing 5):

```
for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
```

And the example:

```css
// Override the normal settings for browsers that dont support translate3D
@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .carousel-inner > .next { left: 16.6667%; }
    .carousel-inner > .prev { left: -16.6667%; }
    .carousel-inner > .active.left { left: -16.6667%; }
    .carousel-inner > .active.right { left: 16.6667%; }
}

// Override translate3D for those that do support it
@media all and (min-width: 1200px) and (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    
    .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        transform: translate3d(16.6667%, 0, 0);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(16.6667%, 0, 0);
    }

    .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        transform: translate3d(-16.6667%, 0, 0);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-16.6667%, 0, 0);
    }   
}
```

I should point out that if you want to make it responsive don't just use `col-lg-2` (unless you only want to show it on screens 1200px or larger). If the size of the images is the problem then you should take a look at [this Codepen example](http://codepen.io/Shawry/pen/MaPBMo) where you can see that you can adjust the number of `.item`s according to the width of the screen (resize the browser window to see).

This method does use Modernizr as a dependancy, but you will only need the [Modernizr.mq()](https://modernizr.com/download/?mq) function which is relatively small. It is used for ascertaining the width within Javascript so that your function can be re-run accordingly. The Modernizr media queries in the example match up with the standard bootstrap breakpoints and should be used in conjunction with the normal `col-*-*` classes to match the desired width of the `.item`. It's probably just best to take a look at the [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/Shawry/pen/MaPBMo). A bit off topic from the question but informative none-the-less